# Is there any way to use custom token program over token program?

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program

I understand that making SPL-tokens is based on token program, and wallets/solscan only recognize token which is made by token program.

What I want to achieve is to make spl-token with custom token program forked by TOKEN_PROGRAM, like I just want to add functionality like 'blocklist' in my token. I can make a forked token program anyway, but wallet and explorer won't accept that custom token.

How can I achieve making spl token with custom TOKEN_PROGRAM? is it possible?

Comment: USDC is known for freezing accounts of hackers and it uses the SPL token program. Perhaps you could just add a wrapper program that freezes people on a block list

Comment: Thx! then I should find USDC spl program

Comment: That's not what i meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot make tokens created with a forked token program appear the same way as regular tokens in standard wallets.

However, you can fork a wallet as well, many wallets are open source. Just fork the wallet, and make it show Bakjuna Tokens in addition to SPL Tokens :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I thought the same way, but I just wanted to know if that is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to convince all token program consuming services to add support to adopt your program implementation.  This is very unlikely to happen if its a one-off implementation with no other popular users